# Internal files of Xampp such as PhpMyAdmin\index.php, htdocs\index.php, config.php, response.php, whitelist.php undergo in debugging mode

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, phpstorm

My Installation are:

- Web Server:**Xampp version 3.2.4**
- IDE: **PhpStorm version 2020.1**
- OS: **Windows 10 Home 64-Bit**
- PHP Version: **7.4.9**

**Problem:**

When I start ONLY PhpMyAdmin in the browser without opening PhpStorm IDE(version 2020.1), then PhpMyAdmin opens happily in the browser without any problem, BUT when I start PhpMyAdmin along with PhpStorm IDE (version 2020.1), Then `PhpMyAdmin\index.php`, `htdocs\index.php`, `config.php`, `OutputBuffering.php`, `response.php`, `whitelist.php`, `message.php` and other internal files of Xampp get displayed in phpStorm IDE and phpMyAdmin page is not displayed in the browser. Also, these internal files of Xampp undergo in debugging mode.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: log file]
[image: Another log file]

**`error.log`**

```
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.726544 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.802080 2020] [core:warn] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.812081 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.849084 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH00455: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.849084 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Aug  4 2020 11:50:23
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.849084 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:23.852085 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8648:tid 624] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3080
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:24.329479 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3080:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:24.404848 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3080:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Oct 30 01:52:24.443850 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3080:tid 632] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Do NOT post codes as screenshot.

Comment: Check the path to: `xampp\apache\logs`, and see if any clues might be in the `error.log`

Comment: please check the error.log file that I have added above

Comment: Try switching off the "Listening for PHP Debug connections" (icon with phone) option in IDE. Does it help?

Comment: You must have configured your Xdebug to automatically attempt to debug **every single script** regardless if "debug me" flag (a COOKIE or GET/POST param) is present. Plus you have "phone handle" icon active (that's what `duck_in_hat` talks about). Either remove such Xdebug "autostart" in php.ini (so debug will be on demand only) or at very least turn off the "phone handle" icon in the IDE (Xdebug will still try to debug, but since it will get no response it will just continue with normal execution after a small delay).